# AC Power Question

Tags: power, ac

I'm not sure if this is the right place to post this but I am stuck on a HW problem with AC power.

[image]

[image]

Any help is appreciated. I feel like my solution is wrong because it seems like the real power should be 20 W but I computed it differently. How do I approach this problem?

Comment: The real power should be 20 watts.

Comment: Both @Andyaka and your instincts are right, of course, as \$P=\frac1{n\,T}\int_{_0}^{^{n\,T}} p_t\:\text{d}t\$. Since the frequency is the same for both cosine terms, the choice for an integral period is simple and the results obvious. The time-varying parts, absorbing and returning power, will cancel out over a full cycle leaving only the remaining constant as the average. Why did you choose your approach?

Comment: @jonk I chose my approach because it was the only way I could think of to draw the power triangle to find Q. reduce the the terms down to S=P+jQ to answer all the questions. Am I missing a trig identity that I need to refresh on?

Comment: @AlecFitz How would you imagine diagramming the cosine terms? For me? I see a vector at 10 degrees and length 20 and another vector at 100 degrees and length 10, rotating about an x-y coordinate system at a rate of 400t. This is a fixed right triangle (with a hypotenuse, of course) where the triangle itself isn't changing, but is only rotating about 0,0. You might also then map the hypotenuse as a vector of its own right on a separate x-y coordinate system that is also rotating at the same rate. Does any of that help?

Comment: @jonk yes, thank you so much for the response. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @AlecFitz Do you feel you have things in hand? Or do you wish something with pretty pictures and spinning vectors? ;)